# How to switch between static color to blur Tab Bar depending on Light/Dark Theme in SwiftUI

Tags: xcode, swiftui, ios15

I tried to do this but it doesn't work properly

```
struct TabBar: View {
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(...) {
            ...
        }
        .onAppear{
            let tabBarAppearance = UITabBarAppearance()

            tabBarAppearance.backgroundColor = colorScheme == .light ? UIColor(named: "color") : .none
            tabBarAppearance.backgroundEffect = colorScheme == .light ? nil : UIBlurEffect(style: .systemThinMaterial)abBarAppearance.stackedItemPositioning = .centered

            UITabBar.appearance().standardAppearance = tabBarAppearance
            UITabBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = tabBarAppearance
        }
        .onChange(of: colorScheme){ [colorScheme] newColor in
            UITabBar.appearance().standardAppearance.backgroundEffect = newColor == .light ? nil : UIBlurEffect(style: .systemThinMaterial)
            UITabBar.appearance().standardAppearance.backgroundColor = newColor == .light ? UIColor(named: "color") : nil
            
        }
    }
}
```

Expected after switching themes:
[light theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdkRA.png)
[dark theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uS1vJ.png)

Comment: What's it showing instead?

Comment: @CharlieReeder https://imgur.com/a/gknAOOX